# UICollection is very slow in showing Image with Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewdelegate

I'm using UICollectionView to show the images in my app.
The problem is that it takes very slow to show images. After 50 seconds, the images in collection view appears. :( 
When I find the solution in google, mostly they write the following codes. 
But it is ***not work*** for me.

```
  cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
  cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

and

```
extension SeeAllCollectionView {

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    debugPrint("seeAllLIStCell Count \(assetsTable.count)")
    return assetsTable.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "seeAllListCell", for: indexPath) as! SeeAllPhotoCell

    let list = assetsTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]


    var imageName: String? = (list.poster_image_url)
    var image: UIImage? = (images_cache[imageName!])
    if image != nil {
        debugPrint("Yes Image")

        cell.imageView.image = image

    } else{
        debugPrint("NO Image")
        cell.imageView.image = nil

        DispatchQueue.main.async(){
            let url = NSURL(string: list.poster_image_url)
            let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
            var image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                cell.movieTitle.text = list.name
                cell.imageView?.image = image
            })
            self.images_cache[imageName!] = image
        }

    }




    return cell
}

}


// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate

extension SeeAllCollectionView {

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            debugPrint("Selected")


    let list = assetsTable[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    debugPrint(list.poster_image_url)
    debugPrint(list.name)

    prefs.set(list.poster_image_url, forKey: "poster_image_url")
    prefs.set(list.name, forKey: "name")
    prefs.set(list.assets_id, forKey: "VIDEO_ID")
    prefs.set(false, forKey: "FLAG")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsChannel") as UIViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Here is my screenshot when I run the project. I got these many lines of codes when I run.
[image]

Please anyone help me how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same `console error` when I am getting the data from the API call and reload the `UITableView` (as per my requirement). My issue is solved by using

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { // load data in back ground mode so that main thread can be safed.
let url = NSURL(string: list.poster_image_url)
            let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
            var image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                cell.movieTitle.text = list.name
                cell.imageView?.image = image
                            }) 
self.images_cache[imageName!] = image       
        }
```

**Screen Shot of Error I got on my Console Before**

[image]

Comment: I tried bro @agent_stack. But still not ok. My processes are I pull the data from server. Pulling process is finish as soon as I reach this collection page. I also look up it debug area . To show these pulled data to UIview, it took so much time and got above warning in debug area bro.

Comment: @MayPhyu bro if your image extraction process gets completed before you show in your UICollectionView the why you are again fetching the image from URL??

Comment: Bro @agent_stack , we have a thousand of images stored in server and we pull 10 images at a time and then show them in collection view. After that, we pull next 10 images.

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async()
```

upon downloading image is probably causing the error, it blocks the main thread and executes network requests on main (UI) queue, not to mention the fact that these requests are then performed serially (therefore slow). Try to change the snippet to:

```
DispatchQueue.global.async(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background){
        let url = NSURL(string: list.poster_image_url)
        let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
        var image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
```

where `global` stands for global queue default for such network operations.

EDIT: apart from using main queue for network calls there may be an issue with actually too many images loaded for rows which are not currently visible on the screen. If there are lot of them and connection is not-so-good you will end up with app pending downloads for onscreen cells. Consider lazy loading images only for onscreen cells - and cancelling downloads for rows which are not visible. There is a quite good [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) (however for table view, but you can easily extend it for collection) in Swift on how to accomplish this.

Comment: bro @WladekSurala,  I use your code. But the error I got is " Amiguous reference to member 'global(priority:)'" .

Comment: @MayPhyu try to replace this call with - DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async { \\download code here}

Comment: bro @WladekSurala, still the same. Still slow and show above lines in command line.

Comment: There will be many rows. I pull the data from server. Pulling process is finish as soon as I reach this collection page. I also look up it debug area . To show these pulled data to UIview, it took so much time and got above warning in debug area bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can give an attempt to [SDWebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) All async Thread operations maintained well.

That can provide following **advantages**

Asynchronously download

Auto Purging Image Cache if memory warnings happen for the app

Image URL caching

Image Caching

Avoid Duplicate Downloads

You can directly use a single method in cell as below

[cell.storeImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] placeholderImage:kDefaultImageForDisplay];

In your code following line should creates problem as that operation can happen on main thread
 let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)